# Non-serializable error when returning response with a selection of documents from a collection in MongoDb. React and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, react-redux

My goal is only to return the complaints belonging to that user.

I have two collections in MongoDB. Users and Complaints. There is one user with one complaint, and another user with two complaints.

I am using Redux to create an initial state as `userComplaints: null`.

For its reducer, I write:  `onlyUserComplaints: (state, { payload }) => { state.userComplaints = payload; localStorage.setItem('userComplaints', JSON.stringify(payload)); },`

Here is the pertinent code for the action, `const config = {
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
};

```
const data = await axios.get(
  `http://localhost:5000/api/complaint/gettingusercomplaints/${userId}`,
  config
);

dispatch(onlyUserComplaints(data))`
```

My route works find in Postman, here it is: `const getAllUserComplaints = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
try {
const userId = req.params.id;

```
const userComplaints = await Complaint.find({ userId });

res.status(201).json(userComplaints);
```

} catch (error) {
throw new AppError(`Something went wrong getting`, 404);
}
});`

For this route, I have a similar get all complaints, where it returns three complaints successfully. The pertinent code is, `const complaints = await Complaint.find({});`

I tried swapping find for findById but that failed in Postman when wanting to only get the complaints for a given user.

Take a look at the actual error:
[image]

So, this is what I don't understand. The data populates fine in Postman. But, when I console.log(userComplaints) the data returned, its type is not a object as it is when I query find({})... when I ask for all the complaints.

Here is more Information:
[image]

[image]
Any ideas?

But POSTMAN is saying it is ok.
[image]

Comment: Don't post pictures of text/code. Copy/paste it into the question with formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Lanxion on discord pointed out that I didn't destructure the data in the response and therefore was getting other things in the header like options.

const {data} = axios...